# how to get hard disk used space ,free space ,not partition free space

Tags: visual-c++

I would like to know the each hard disk's free space ,used space ,not partition free space thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the GetDiskFreeSpaceEx function. 
See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx